# Is it possible to override the creation of a new object and return an existing object?

Tags: vb.net

So a quick non working example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Public Class repclass
    Public Shared rep As repclass
    Public n As Integer

    Public Sub New(n As Integer)
        If Not rep Is Nothing Then
            'replace me with the existing thing like
            Me = rep
            'or
            return rep
            'or something that actually works here
        Else
            Me.n = n
            rep = Me
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is that possible?

Comment: No.  Google "factory method".

Comment: (You may be interested in an IoC container.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what yo are looking for is the Singleton design pattern that ensures there is only a single instance of a class. See [Implementing Singleton in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx). Here is the example converted to VB:

```
Public Class Singleton
    Private Shared m_instance As Singleton

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As Singleton
        Get
            If m_instance Is Nothing Then
                m_instance = New Singleton()
            End If
            Return m_instance
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Well the example was simplified, I actually do need multiple instances but they need to be unique in respects to a parameter of the class but that will work regardless!

Comment: @JakeFreelander: Make a dictionary, add a "Get" method - it will create new instance or use existing one, based on parameters that are being passed.